# Why react re-creates all the items on the list and shouldComponentUpdate never called

Tags: reactjs

How to avoid re-rendering the whole list given the following code?
For all the items of the list the shouldComponentUpdate is never called when the parent component props changes and all of the items are re-mounted anew.

The parent list component:

```
class TaskList extends React.Component {
tasksList = (tasks) => {
    return _.map(tasks, (task) => (<TaskCard key={task.id} task={task}/>));
};

render() {
    const {tasks, loadMore} = this.props;
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div id="tasks-list">
                    {this.tasksList(tasks)}
            </div>

            <div>
                <button type="button" onClick={loadMore}>Load more</button>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

The child item component:

```
class TaskCard extends React.Component {
componentWillMount() {
    console.log('component will always mount');
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    console.log('should component update never called');
}

render() {
    const {task} = this.props;

    return (
        <div key={task.id}>
            <div className="card">
                <div className="card-header">{renderStatus(task.status)}{task.url}</div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <TaskResults task={task}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The loadMore method which is on the button click adds new tasks in the list along with the old ones. I don't wand the old ones being re-rendered.
Thank you very much for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I found what the problem was, 
the code above is a working one and actually the problem was with how I create the parent component

```
export default withTasks(TaskList);
```

This HOC recreated the parent list every time the props changed so what and how creates the parent component is very important.
Thanks